# LDAP/AD - How to determine whether user name or password is mismatch

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, java-security

In my application, I am using LDAP bind authentication mechanism. I am getting AuthenticationException commonly even if any one is mismatch(user name or password). 
            I want to show error message either User Name is mismatch or Password mismatch. Currently, Using AuthenticationException not able to get the proper details.

Is there any existing API will help? or need to query using API?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If users give username and password for authentication, it's best practice not to tell them the exact reason why a log on wasn't successful.  You always tell them there's a mismatch between username and password, so an attacker doesn't learn if a particular username exists.

Comment: I am not showing which one is wrong in the UI, but my code needs to understand which one is mismatch either user name or password

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the best practice is not to tell the reason.

--

But if you have to do it no matter what:

Do a `search` with the Username to check if the Username exists. If it doesn't exist it's an error.

If user exists and it continues to authenticate but you get AuthenticationException then it's a wrong password.

--

Edit:

```
If(checkUserExists(username)){
    //construct the hashtable environment
    //...
    ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username); 
    ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, password); 
    //...
    try {
        localLdapContent = new InitialLdapContext(ht, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //suppose it's a wrong password
    }
}else{
    //error user doesn't exist
}
```

You need another ldap connection with the permission to check user for all requests.

```
boolean checkUserExists(String username) {
    //...
    ht_administrator.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, admin_username); 
    ht_administrator.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, admin_password); 
    //...
    adminconn = new InitialLdapContext(ht_administrator, null);
    return adminconn.search(
        "uid="+username+",ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", "(objectclass=*)", searchControls
    ).hasMore();
}
```

Comment: I don't have global context. Is it way to query the user id is exists or not without providing password(hand shaking the ldap server)?

Comment: You can simply instantiate `new InitialLdapContext` with administrator username and password for doing the search.

Comment: It's like using an administrator's account (or any account with sufficient permissions) to query any user.

Answer (score 0):

The [returned error codes](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) from Microsoft Active Directory provide that information.

"The exception is [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0Cxxxxxx, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data , vece ]."

The data  values will inform of the issue.

Comment: For both user name and password mismatch, I am getting same error message "javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece
"

Comment: Is there any  way to query the user id is exists or not without providing password(hand shaking the ldap server)?